# Don't show hidden files in a directory listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have code that generates a listview directory of my computer. When I open the C directory it shows $RECYCLE.Bin. Is there anyway to have it where it doesn't show these files?

```
foreach (string dir in folders)
{
    dirData[0] = dir.ToString();
    dirData[1] = dir.Length.ToString();
    dirData[2] = File.GetLastAccessTime(dir).ToString();
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dirData, imageList1.Images.Count - 1);
    lv.Tag = dir;

    imageList1.Images.Add(BlackFox.Win32.Icons.IconFromExtensionShell(".*", BlackFox.Win32.Icons.SystemIconSize.Small).ToBitmap());

    listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
}
```

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times, please..

Comment: :) i just want to ask is there anyway that systemfiles are handled in c# listview...is it madatory that i copypaste my whole code :/

Comment: you should post some of your code. We can't guess what you have in your IDE and this question does not have a answer without the code

Comment: @engineer41 - Not necessarily your "whole code", but at least **relevant** code to the issue you're having. Your question is just too vague without a sample of the code you've written.

Comment: update...sorry for the botheration

Comment: Do you not need to create new `dirDate` in every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\")
.Where(d => !new DirectoryInfo(d).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden));

foreach (string dir in folders)
{
   .....
```

Let me expand on the answer as some people may find it difficult to understand, This will ignore `SystemHidden` directrories.

ie:

`"C:\\$Recycle.Bin"`

`"C:\\Documents and Settings"`

`"C:\\System Volume Information"`

If you want to ignore all hidden directories you can simply omit the `FileAttributes.System` attribute from the linq statement but this would result in losing directories like `ProgramData`  in your `ListView` which I'm not sure you want.

Comment: Your answer would return dirs which are only `System` or `Hidden`. You are trying to copy my answer and simplify it but it is not correct.

Comment: Read the code, it clearly returns anything tha is NOT System/Hidden, And I am not copying your code as most of your lines are not needed at all and is confusing for a simple operation.

Comment: sa_ddam213, I did more than reading your code and tested it. It returns invalid results, for example `only-Hidden` directories like *ProgramData* or *C:\$AVG8.VAULT$*

Comment: What are you talking about, `!` means false, I have no idea why it does not work for you, I have been using this line of code for YEARS

Comment: What are **you** talking about. Have you tested your code?

Comment: Guess it worked for OP too :)

Comment: No it doesn't work fine. Just make a directory hidden and run your code.

Comment: It doesn't matter what OP chooses. I just want to warn future readers.

Comment: The op wants to hide recycle bin which has System and Hidden attributes, he never said anything about only hidden folders, But since you seem sure he wants to hide all hidden directorys I will upvote yours and delete mine :)

Comment: No you know it wrong, you don't get extra reps with being funny :)

Comment: Whats your problem man, This will hide hidden system folders which is what he asked for

Answer (score 3):

```
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\")
             .Select(d => new { Attr = new DirectoryInfo(d).Attributes, Dir = d })
             .Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
             .Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
             .Select(x => x.Dir)
             .ToList();
```

This will not only ignore `System+Hidden` directories like `C:\$Recycle.Bin` but also `C:\$AVG8.VAULT$` which is not a `System` directory and used by virus scanner.

Comment: You could change your `where` clause to this: `.Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System && !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)`

Comment: @CAbbott why? I find this more readible.

Comment: @CAbbott Could. It's a matter of taste, I think. I like the fully chained where-clauses, because they're simple to remove/add/change.

Comment: i dont understand this alian VB lang..but i guess u r saying to specify that fileattribute !=hidden

Comment: ... it's C#. Linq, using method expression syntax, with lambda predicates, to be precise.

Comment: @J.Steen - Fair enough. There's just an assumption of an "and" when chaining where clauses, whereas I like to be more explicit with the where conditions.

Comment: @CAbbott Absolutely agreed. Or-cases are very hard to do, like that, unless you decide to build your own huge Expression. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run an iterate over the listview items and remove items which they extension is .bin.

you can find .bin with this piece of code (pseudonymous):

```
for(int i=0;i<items_count;i++)
{
  if(listview1.items[i].Substring(listview1.items[i].length-3,listview1.items[i].length)=="bin")
   listview1.items.remove(i);
}
```

another pseudonymous :
if you want to generalize this , you should use file attribute class like this for a list view item :

```
string filePath = listview1.items[i];

// get file attributes
System.IO.FileAttributes fileAttributes = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath);
```

Now you should check if fileAttributes is hidden , remove the correspond item.

Note : Next Time , Please send some of your code lines , it is better for problem salvation.