# Hiding system and hidden files in a treeview file explorer

Tags: c#

I have a treeview in a C# Winforms application that displays directories with hidden and system files

```
 public TreeNode GetDirectory(TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(parentNode.FullPath);
        DirectoryInfo[] dInfo = d.GetDirectories()
                                  .Where(di => !di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
                                  .Where(di => !di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                                  .ToArray();
        parentNode.Nodes.Clear();
            if (dInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo driSub in dInfo)
                {
                    treeNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(driSub.Name);
                    treeNode.Nodes.Add("");

                }
            }
```

error is Error  1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Read other answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223076/dont-show-hidden-files-in-a-directory-listview/14223214#14223214)

Comment: i have read it and im trying to add it but it says that where clause cant be called with system.array types...i have tried to convert it but no good

Comment: I meant `other answers` not the one you accepted.

Comment: system.Array doent contain a defination of directoryInfo

Comment: And you need **AT LEAST tell us** what exactly that error and that exception are!

Comment: 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? when i use it like 

 DirectoryInfo dirs = new DirectoryInfo(parentNode.FullPath + "\\")
             .Select(d => new { Attr = new DirectoryInfo(d).Attributes, Dir = d })
             .Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
             .Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
             .Select(x => x.Dir)
             .ToList();

Comment: @engineer41 If you read the answer carefully they use *Linq* on `GetDirectories` not on DirectoryInfo. Since it is a single class not *Enumerable*

Comment: when i use it like this it says system.array doest contain a definition for select `DirectoryInfo[] dInfo = d.GetDirectories().Select(di => new { Attr = new DirectoryInfo(di).Attributes, Dir = di })
             .Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
             .Where(x => !x.Attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
             .Select(x => x.Dir)
             .ToList();`

Comment: ur understanding my problem....but u r still not helping me..ur not fair @14V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
DirectoryInfo[] dInfo = d.GetDirectories()
                          .Where(di => !di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
                          .Where(di => !di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: i have updated my questionwith error plz have a look

Comment: @engineer41 Don't forget to include `using System.Linq`